# How can I use show method of the jquery ui without any effects?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need the jQuery-UI on the page, because I am using draggable and other features. jQuery-UI overrides the `.show()` method of the jQuery. It forces me to specify at least one argument which represents the effect. But I want to use the `.show()` method without any arguments and any effects, just simple as in jQuery. How can I do this?

Comment: *"jquery-ui overrides the .show() method of the jquery. It forces me to specify at least one argument"*... are you sure that's correct? I feel fairly certain that it is not.

Comment: simply don't include an argument, the arguments are optional. If you are finding otherwise, post an example showing that because it goes against the documentation. http://jsfiddle.net/rEdNb/

Comment: @WesleyMurch: [how](http://api.jquery.com/show/) [certain](http://api.jqueryui.com/show/)?

Comment: @Brad: [Fairly certain](http://jsfiddle.net/rNYsf/) an argument is not required as the OP states.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I'm just pointing out that it does extend it, though [keeps original behavior when possible](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.effect.js#L1127). ;-)

Comment: Sorry, it seems that problem was caused by me. I was surprised, but all was fine, before I added jquery-ui to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
show: {
    show: null;
}
```

> "If the value is falsey, then no animation will occur and the element
>   will be shown immediately."

Taken from: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#added-_show-and-_hide-methods-to-support-show-and-hide-options